# Call rest service in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I have created a restfull service in Node server like this

```
    express().use('/getdata', express()
            .get('/', function (req, res) {
                //....                  
            })
            .put('/', function (req, res) {
                //....
            })
       );
```

Its working fine when I do a GET or PUT to **http ://localhost/getdata** from front-end /browser.

So how can to do the same in **node server** basically , make a get request in node server using HTTP object. How the **url path** will be ?

Comment: very neat that you can chain the express routes together like that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is the same as for your browser:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://localhost/getdata/', function(res) {
  ...
});
```

If you want to make a `PUT` request, use [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) instead:

```
http.request({
  path   : '/getdata/',
  method : 'PUT',
  ...
}, function(res) {
  ...
});
```